# Perl: Installation of Statistics::Normality fails

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install Perl's `Statistics::Normality` (https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::Normality) but I am getting errors I don't know how to fix on the command line from CPAN 2.26 and perl 5.26.1

I've tried the installation instructions on that page, but they produce errors

```
Reading '/home/con/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'   Database was generated on Tue, 02 Apr 2019 16:17:03 GMT Running install for module 'Statistics::Normality' Checksum for /home/con/.local/share/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MW/MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz ok Scanning cache /home/con/.local/share/.cpan/build for sizes ............................................................................DONE Configuring M/MW/MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz with Makefile.PL Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good Generating a Unix-style Makefile Writing Makefile for Statistics::Normality Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json   MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz   /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK Running make for M/MW/MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz cp lib/Statistics/Normality.pm blib/lib/Statistics/Normality.pm Manifying 1 pod document   MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz   /usr/bin/make -- OK Running make test for MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/00-load.t ....... 1/1 # Testing Statistics::Normality 0.01, Perl 5.026001, /usr/bin/perl t/00-load.t ....... ok    t/01-normality.t .. 1/? # Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen. t/01-normality.t .. Dubious, test returned 254 (wstat 65024, 0xfe00) All 4 subtests passed  t/pod-coverage.t .. 1/1 
#   Failed test 'Pod coverage on Statistics::Normality'
#   at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.0/Test/Pod/Coverage.pm line 133.
# Coverage for Statistics::Normality is 0.0%, with 2 naked subroutines:
#   dagostino_k_square_test
#   shapiro_wilk_test
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1. t/pod-coverage.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100) Failed 1/1 subtests  t/pod.t ........... ok   

Test Summary Report
------------------- t/01-normality.t (Wstat: 65024 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)   Non-zero exit status: 254   Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output t/pod-coverage.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)   Failed test:  1   Non-zero exit status: 1 Files=4, Tests=7,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr
0.00 sys +  0.18 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.22 CPU) Result: FAIL Failed 2/4 test programs. 1/7 subtests failed. Makefile:822: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255   MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz   /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK //hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:   reports MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz Failed during this command:  MWENDL/Statistics-Normality-0.01.tar.gz      : make_test NO
```

I have no idea how to fix this :(

Comment: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=107810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the only test error, it's a documentation issue and nothing to worry about. Install the module forcefully.

```
$ cpan -f Statistics::Normality
```

Comment: Between the pod error and not identifying `Statistics::Distributions` as a prerequisite, [this module does not test very well](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Statistics-Normality+0.01).

Comment: I was afraid to use the "-f" option as I thought it would break it somehow.  Thank you!